# error: cannot find symbol при наследовании в директории databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, исключения, binding, android-data-binding

При запуске проекта возникает ошибка:

```
error: cannot find symbol
public class FilmItemBindingImpl extends FilmItemBinding  {
                                         ^
  symbol: class FilmItemBinding
```

Родительский класс, с которым возникла проблемма, подчёркивается, а не выделяется красным (то есть, вроде как Android Studio его видит):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Та же ситуация со всеми классами в директории `databinding`

Код:

```
package com.example.roommoviemvvm.databinding;
import com.example.roommoviemvvm.R;
import com.example.roommoviemvvm.BR;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class FilmItemBindingImpl extends FilmItemBinding  {

    @Nullable
    private static final androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.IncludedLayouts sIncludes;
    @Nullable
    private static final android.util.SparseIntArray sViewsWithIds;
    static {
        sIncludes = null;
        sViewsWithIds = new android.util.SparseIntArray();
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.contentCardFilm, 1);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.idFilm, 2);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.nameFilm, 3);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.categoryFilm, 4);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.priceFilm, 5);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.editFilm, 6);
        sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.deleteFilm, 7);
    }
    // views
    // variables
    // values
    // listeners
    // Inverse Binding Event Handlers

    public FilmItemBindingImpl(@Nullable androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, @NonNull View root) {
        this(bindingComponent, root, mapBindings(bindingComponent, root, 8, sIncludes, sViewsWithIds));
    }
    private FilmItemBindingImpl(androidx.databinding.DataBindingComponent bindingComponent, View root, Object[] bindings) {
        super(bindingComponent, root, 0
            , (com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView) bindings[0]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[4]
            , (androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout) bindings[1]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton) bindings[7]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton) bindings[6]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[2]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[3]
            , (androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView) bindings[5]
            );
        this.cardFilm.setTag(null);
        setRootTag(root);
        // listeners
        invalidateAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateAll() {
        synchronized(this) {
                mDirtyFlags = 0x1L;
        }
        requestRebind();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPendingBindings() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (mDirtyFlags != 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setVariable(int variableId, @Nullable Object variable)  {
        boolean variableSet = true;
            return variableSet;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onFieldChange(int localFieldId, Object object, int fieldId) {
        switch (localFieldId) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeBindings() {
        long dirtyFlags = 0;
        synchronized(this) {
            dirtyFlags = mDirtyFlags;
            mDirtyFlags = 0;
        }
        // batch finished
    }
    // Listener Stub Implementations
    // callback impls
    // dirty flag
    private  long mDirtyFlags = 0xffffffffffffffffL;
    /* flag mapping
        flag 0 (0x1L): null
    flag mapping end*/
    //end
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать File > Invalidate Caches/Restart... и выбрать Invalidate Caches and Restart. Видел подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126670/android-data-binding-error-cannot-find-symbol-class?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), тут помог этот вариант.